# Inserting a node in a hashtable

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

The code below is correct but I do not understand why 2 lines of the code work. I am referring to the last else block. Specifically, I am referring to these 2 lines:

newWord->next = hashtable[index];
hashtable[index] = newWord;

If the goal is to append the node to the linked list at an index of the hash table, why is newWord->next pointing to the index of the hashtable when there are presumably nodes already at that index. I would think it should be newWord->next = NULL since that node would be the last link in the linked list and, therefore, should point to NULL. From the code, it looks like the "next" field of the struct is referencing the index. I hope I'm making sense.
    /**
     * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
     */

```
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    // opens dictionary
    FILE* file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return false;

// create an array for word to be stored in
char word[LENGTH+1];

// scan through the file, loading each word into the hash table
while (fscanf(file, "%s\n", word)!= EOF)
{
    // increment dictionary size
    dictionarySize++;

    // allocate memory for new word 
    node* newWord = malloc(sizeof(node));

    // put word in the new node
    strcpy(newWord->word, word);

    // find what index of the array the word should go in
    int index = hash(word);

    // if hashtable is empty at index, insert
    if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
    {
        hashtable[index] = newWord;
        newWord->next = NULL;
    }

    // if hashtable is not empty at index, append
    else
    {
        newWord->next = hashtable[index];
        hashtable[index] = newWord;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that the new node is appended to the end is wrong. The code inserts the new node at the front of the linked list, effectively making it the new head. The "tail" is the old list and its head is now the node after the new head.

This kind of insertion is faster, because you don't have to walk the list to find the end. The order of the nodes doesn't matter here.

You don't even need the distinction in `if (hashtable[index] == NULL)`; you can collapse the two cases into one, namely the code in the `else` clause.